# How to calculate acceleration needed based on existing acceleration/velocity rules

Tags: c++, math, physics, acceleration

I have 3 values that determine an object's movement: `velocity`, `acceleration`, and `maxVelocity`. I also have a `distance` value that determines how close they are to their target (basically an X). This code runs each frame to determine actual movement based on the 3 values:

```
var velocityDelta = (Math.max(Math.min(velocity + (acceleration * 0.016), maxVelocity), -maxVelocity) - velocity) / 2;
velocity += velocityDelta;
var delta = velocity*0.016;
velocity += velocityDelta;
distance -= delta;
```

If that `velocityDelta` is a bit confusing it's basically this:

```
velocityDelta = velocity + (acceleration * 0.016);
if (velocityDelta > maxVelocity) velocityDelta = maxVelocity;
else if (velocityDelta < -maxVelocity) velocityDelta = -maxVelocity;
velocityDelta = (velocityDelta - velocity) / 2;
```

Now, assuming you can ONLY change the the value of `acceleration`, is there a way to calculate what acceleration you'll need in order to ensure that `distance` will end up at exactly 0?  Meaning during one of the frames in which the above code is run, `distance - delta == 0`. So assume the code looks like this:

```
var distance = 300.5;
var velocity = 125.86;
var maxVelocity = 300;
while (distance != 0) {
    acceleration = ?
    var velocityDelta = (Math.max(Math.min(velocity + (acceleration * 0.016), maxVelocity), -maxVelocity) - velocity) / 2;
    velocity += velocityDelta;
    var delta = velocity*0.016;
    velocity += velocityDelta;
    distance -= delta;
}
```

What value would you put into `acceleration` to ensure that the loop doesn't run forever? Assuming distance/velocity/max can be any number that you can't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is pretty underconstrained. I'll suppose that the best solution is to decelerate (i.e. accelerate in the direction opposite to velocity) so that `maxVelocity` won't be a problem.

First, find out how many time intervals there will be before the object reaches the target (assuming no acceleration):

```
var dt = 0.016;
var jumps = distance/(dt * velocity);   <-- round DOWN
```

Then apply some basic physics to travel `distance` in that amount of time:

```
x = vt + at^2/2
a = 2(x-vt)/t^2
acceleration = 2*(distance - velocity*jumps*dt)/(jumps*dt*jumps*dt);
```

This works pretty well. There's a slight kludge in there that bothers me a little, but I don't feel like tracking down right now-- it probably cancels out a kludge in the code.